# ¿Cómo puedo crear un formulario con una lista desplegable?

Tags: html, django, django-forms

form.py

```
from django import forms

generos= [
    ('hetero', 'Heterosexual'),
    ('homo', 'Homosexual'),
    ('bi', 'Bisexual'),
    ('ase', 'Asexual'),
    ('pan', 'Pansexual'),
    ]

class formulario(forms.Form):
    nombre= forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    apellido= forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    genero= forms.CharField(label='Seleccione su genero', widget=forms.Select(choices=genero))
    comentario= forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

formulario.html

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>Sergito</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
            <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="page-header" align="center">
                <h1>Esto es una prueba</h1>
                <a href="post_list">Inicio</a>
                <a href="formulario">Formulario</a>
                <a href="tabla">Tabla</a>
            </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-group">
            <p>{{ formulario.nombre.label }}</p>

            {{ formulario.nombre.errors }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>{{ formulario.genero.label }}</p>
            {{ formulario.genero.errors }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>{{ formulario.comentario.label }}</p>
            {{ formulario.comentario.errors }}
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader, Context
from blog.models import *
from django.core import serializers
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django import forms


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'formulario.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formulario'] = formulario()

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        nombre = request.POST.get('nombre')
        genero = request.POST.get('genero')
        comentario = request.POST.get('comentario')

        print("Nombre")
        print(nombre)
        print('-----------------')
        print("genero")
        print(genero)
        print('-----------------')
        print("comentario")
        print(comentario)

        return redirect('blog/formulario')


# Aca se crean tus vistas

def post_list(request):
    # Codigo que quieras
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html')

def formulario(request):
    # Codigo que quieras
    return render(request, 'blog/formulario.html')

def tabla(request):
    #codigo que quieras
    return render(request, 'blog/tabla.html')
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Qué problema tienes con el código que nos compartes?

Answer (score 0):

`forms.CharField` solo genera un input de tipo texto.

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
 genero = forms.ChoiceField(choices=generos, required=True, label="Seleccione su género")
```

El campo ChoiceField crea una lista desplegable, en este caso con los géneros ya definidos antes.

Comment: eso que problema resuelve?

Comment: El campo ChoiceField crea una lista desplegable, en este caso con los géneros que ha definido Mauricio. El tenia forms.CharField que solo genera un input de tipo texto.

Comment: Perfecto lo agrego a la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre el tema de la lista desplegable tu mejor opción es hacer lo que dice @VicenteAlmea usando un [`forms.ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) ya que renderiza automaticamente en un `Select` widget (una lista desplegable).

El verdadero problema en tu template es que lo único que estás haciendo es renderizar los labels (nombres de los campos) y sus errores. Tomando como ejemplo el campo `nombre`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p>{{ formulario.nombre.label }}</p>
    {{ formulario.nombre.errors }}
</div>
```

Tienes que renderizar también el campo en sí:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{ formulario.nombre.label }}</label>
    {{formulario.nombre}}
    <p class="text-danger">{{ formulario.nombre.errors }}</p>
</div>
```

Intenta hacerlo con todos tus campos y el formulario debería renderizar sin problemas.